# Set time from DatePicker for reminder

Tags: swift, timer, notifications, intervals, reminders

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9HzP.jpg) (I try to create something like this.
Now u can see, here you may choose time and interval)

I created reminder, where a user can choose how often to receive notifications (every 2 days, every 3 days etc.), but I also want the user to be able to choose the time. I know how to create reminder which will send notifications at the selected time, but I have to use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`, and problem is that I use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`. Thank you

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    
@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

 @IBAction func setReminderBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Test"
        content.body = "Blablabla"
        content.sound = .default
        

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval((picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)+1)*(24*3600)), repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "blabla.reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
   
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error")
            }
        }
        print("Notification added")
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
private func setLocalNotification(hour: Int, minute: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
   
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { [weak self] (granted, error) in
        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        
        guard error == nil else {
            completionHandler(false)
            return
        }
        
        if granted {
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "title"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            content.badge = 1
            
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.hour = hour
            dateComponents.minute = minute
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
            
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            center.add(request)
            
            completionHandler(true)
            return
        }
        
        completionHandler(false)
    }
}
```

and you can call by get date from datePicker like this:

```
let date = self.timepPicker.date
let calendar = Calendar.current
   let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date) // get hour
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date) // get minute

self.setLocalNotification(hour: hour, minute: minutes) { [weak self] isSet in
    guard let self = self else {
        return
    }

    if !isSet {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() // remove previus notification
    }
}
```

update answer for
repeat X time in every n day:

create extension from date for create simple date getDateComponents:

```
extension Date {
    public func getDateComponents() -> DateComponents {
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .day], from: self)
        
        return dateComponents
    }
}
```

and update setLocalNotification function:

```
private func setLocalNotification(repeatCount: Int, jumpNextDay: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            if granted {
                
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "title"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                content.badge = 1
                
                // create date from hour and minute based on current
                let firstDate = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minute, second: 0, of: Date())!
                
                let firstTimeInterval = firstDate.timeIntervalSince1970 // get timeInterval
                
                // example run for
                // repeat count 5 and jump 2
                // 2 4 6 8 10
                for i in stride(from: jumpNextDay, to: jumpNextDay * (repeatCount + 1), by: jumpNextDay) {

                    // create next day
                    // 86400 next time interval added to first time interval
                    
                    // create time interval from first date

                    // 2 next day = firstTimeInterval + 2 * 86400
                    
                    let timeIntervalForTrigger = firstTimeInterval + Double((i * 86400))
                    
                    // create date from time interval
                    let date = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: timeIntervalForTrigger)
                    
                    // create datecomponnet
                    let dateComponents = date.getDateComponents()
                    
                    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

                    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                    center.add(request)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and call:

```
let date = self.timepPicker.date
        let calendar = Calendar.current
           let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date) // get hour
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date) // get minute

        self.setLocalNotification(repeatCount: 2, jumpNextDay: 2, hour: hour, minute: minutes)
```

Comment: Excuse me, your code works, but when I change interval (number of days how often to receive notification), notifications comes every day. So works or by day, or by time, but I try to set up two things together. For example set up notifications every X days(which I choose by picker) at X time (which I also choose by picker). This is the problem. :( because if I choose interval I use UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger, if I choose time I use UNCalendarNotificationTrigger

Comment: append new Approach to my asnwer, Look again

Comment: Yes, it works notifications comes every 2 days and repeat 2 times like in this line (self.setLocalNotification(repeatCount: 2, jumpNextDay: 2, hour: hour, minute: minutes)) at time what I selected from timePicker. But I also have another picker for interval, so I don't understand how can i do "jumpNextDay" from picker and repeat it infinitely... p.s. I'm new, so I'm sorry if I don't understand simple things

Comment: If you wish, you can send the UI you need to implement with the work flow here so that I can help you.

Comment: I updated my question and added a photo     :)

Comment: hi @hessam I am struggling with a similar kind of problem. Is there anyway you could help me? I have to send notifications every other day starting from the date selected from the calendar.